# How does css container width and overflow property work?

Tags: css

Hi I have this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hivunuga/1) here, it should look like:

[image]

My questions are:

**Questions1 :**

What does the 400% do? Why we need to set this?

```
#slides .inner {
  width: 400%;
}
```

**Question2:**

If I comment out `overflow` like this:

```
#overflow {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

it will look like this, even I have set the `max-width` to be 300px

[image]

But if I keep the `overflow` and comment out the two `width`

```
#overflow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slides .inner {
  /* width: 400%; */
}
#slides article {
  /* width: 25%; */
  float: left;
}
```

It will look like: [image]

Shouldn't all the image block goes to the same row as shown in the picture above?

**Question3:**

Why we need to set the width? If I comment out `width: 25%;` it will still work properly.

```
#slides article {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: content **does not need** to be inside the parent. Limiting your parent to `300px` does not mean all the content should be inside. That's why we have `overflow` to control how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

The #slides .inner is set to width: 400%; because you have 4 slides and you want each slide to take up 100% of the parent element, in this case the 300px #slides div.

```
#slides .inner {
width: 400%;
}
```

**Question 2:**

The "overflow: hidden;" is called to hide the other 300% and only display them while they are the active slide in the 300px #slides div.

When you remove "overflow: hidden;" all of the slides are displayed but the actual #slides div itself is still just 300px.

When you comment out the "width: 400%;" The elements stack because the width falls back to 300px defined by:

```
#slider {
max-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is *pointless* if you give `overflow:hidden` along  with `width:100%`
you sholud give `width` or `max-width` in `px` inorder for the `overflow:hidden` get effect..!!

**Note:** Anybody can correct me if i am wrong..!!

if  you try
this

http://jsbin.com/hivunuga/7/edit

**CSS**

```
#slider {
  max-width:300px;

  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#overflow {
  width: 100%;

}

#slides .inner {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

you will know why we need `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

*What does the 400% do?*

```
#slides .inner {
  width: 400%;
}
```

This will set the width of element `.inner` to 4 times (400%) the width of its parent.

**Question 2:**

*If I comment out overflow like this:*

```
#overflow {
  width: 100%;
  //overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is not a valid comment in CSS, and will cause an error or unwanted styling. Try commenting like this:

```
/* This is a CSS comment */
```

Comment: I have modified the code, results are still the same

Comment: the `//` is invalid but looks like ***jsbin*** treats it as a valid comment sign (which is very useful).

Comment: why we need to set the width of element .inner to 4 times (400%) the width of its parent? if it is 4 x 300px, then shouldn't all the image block show in one row instead of stacked on each other?